# How do LCDs vary light intensity?

Tags: visible-light, condensed-matter, polarization, applied-physics

What exactly happens when an electric field is applied?
Say we're dealing with a TN LCD, in a 'normally white' mode.
With no voltage applied, the orthogonal grated plates cause the director of the LC to twist and form a helical shape which turns the polarization angle of incident light (like in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOKd6.png) image from wikipedia). 
When the maximum electric field is applied, all molecules get tilted by 90 degrees perpendicular to the twisting plane, which ruins the helical shape and stops the turning of the polarization angle - thus causing no light to pass.

My question is what happens when a weaker electric field is applied? The naive answer would be that the polarization is turned to a smaller angle, but there are a few reasons to suspect it's not as simple as that. For example, the gratings themselves are still perpendicular to each other - so the overall twist is still 90 degrees. I was thinking that maybe this only means that the efficiency of the twist is reduced (i.e. only a fraction of polarized light is turned by 90 degrees) which will cause an effective turning because of the superposition of turned of unturned light. But since the LC is birefringent this will induce a phase difference and actually cause the polarization to become elliptic, and hence the second linear polarizer won't block it well.

I have found no literature on this matter and would love to get an answer or a reference in which I could read about it (hopefully with mathematical description e.g. the LC's jones matrix's dependence on the applied voltage).

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaking, but from what I know the LCD twist is proportional to the applied voltage (the the applied electric field).

This is the working principle of LDC TVs, the twist of the polarization angle is proportional to the applied voltage. Light is polarized behind the TV plates and the applied voltage on the plates allows the intensity of light that goes through them to become modulated. This is the Faraday Effect.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
Actually the Faraday Effect is somewhat different - it is what happens in a **circular** birefringent material, in which the two circular polarizations have different velocities. 
Liquid crystals are linearly birefringent (they have a fast and slow axis), and still this is not what rotates the light. The rotation is caused by the actual twist of the LC's director (which is fixed and caused by the gratings on both sides of the LC).
The fact that it has linear birefringence is the reason I am asking about the polarization state of the light coming out of the crystal.

Comment: You have two perpendicular polarizers. When there is no twist through the LCD between these two polarizers, there is no light that goes through them. The LCD twist is proportional to the applied voltage thus a part of the light that goes through polarizer 1 goes through polarizer 2 when a voltage is applied to the LCD.

Comment: It is true that when both polarizers are there, the amount of transmitted light is proportional to voltage. But I think it is a bit more complicated if you look at the light coming out before the 2nd polarizer. Do you have any reference for the math\physics of the polarized light inside the LC itself? Because all I could find is the dependence of *transmitted light* on the voltage, and not the angle twist. As I said in the original post, I think these two are not the same. I did a little test to check the answer and the result might indicate that the light coming out is not linearly polarized

Comment: https://www.physlink.com/education/askexperts/ae532.cfm

Comment: In this link the author only talks about a 90 degree polarization rotation, which can be turned on or off (he does not talk about intermediate angles):
"Based on what direction the molecules are pointed compared to the polarization of incoming light and the thickness of the liquid crystal sample, the incoming light's polarization either gets rotated by 90 degrees passing through the sample or not at all."

Comment: When I was a child I had an electronic watch. The segments of the electronic watch were white or dark. There was no intermediate gray. You are right, the LCD layer twists light at right angles (at 90 degrees).  Thus light of one color is allowed to go through the polarizers and the LCD layer, or not. To have the desired brightness of that color more or less pixels have to be turned on or off.